# Two past tenses in one sentence

Tags: grammar

Is it correct to use two tense in one sentence? Like

I have just clicked on the cross button and nothing happened.

Or I clicked on ... and nothing happened.
Indeed, two actions (one after the other) in a sentence implicate the use of the past simple even if it's recent?

Comment: There's no good reason for using the *Perfect* form for the first verb, but that doesn't mean it's "incorrect". Equally, it wouldn't be incorrect to *repeat* the Perfect for the sale of "consistency": *I **have** just clicked on the cross button and nothing **has** happened.* Some people might think using the Perfect (especially, *twice*) conveys a greater sense of "immediacy" (closeness / relevance to time of speaking), but at the end of the day it's just a (less common) stylistic choice.

Comment: The standard usage for certain adverbs is the present perfect: 'just', 'yet', 'still' and 'already' https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/b1-b2-grammar/just-yet-still-and-already The meaning with just PP and just SP are slightly different. IF there were no  difference, the British Council (and others) wouldn't bother with it.

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence is correct.  There is no rule in English grammar (or the grammar of any language that I'm aware of) that says that all verb must have the same tense.

In this sentence the first part is reasonable in a present perfect tense. It provides an implied time for the second part of the sentence, which is therefore in the past tense.  You would understand this as being equivalent to

> I've just clicked on the cross, and when I clicked on the cross, nothing happened.

This doesn't mean that other expressions are wrong.  You could have used the past tense too.

Comment: thank you, so I can say "when i clicked on the cross, nothing happenend" even if the action is just after "I ve just clicked on the cross" ?

Comment: Yes "When I clicked on the cross, nothing happened." is a correct sentence. You say it even if the action is just after clicking on the cross.

Answer (score 0):

I have just clicked on the cross button and nothing happened.
Right.
Why?
Two reasons: ***just* takes the present perfect in standard English**
and the present perfect refers to the moment you utter the phrase in the present.

And right after that moment, nothing happened. Strictly speaking, it might sound odd but those two together (PP and SP) like that are idiomatic.

You can also just use: I clicked on x and nothing happened.

This is what the British Council says:

> Grammar explanation We often use just, yet, still and already with the
> present perfect because **they are related to the present moment.**
> This page focuses on the meaning and use of these words when they are
> used with the present perfect.
>
> just Just used with the present perfect means 'a short time before'.

[British Council](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/b1-b2-grammar/just-yet-still-and-already)

PLEASE NOTE: You can use "just" with the simple past, but the standard usage us given above but the emphasis is slightly different.

Comment: Your highlighted text implies that Present Perfect is actually *more likely than Simple Past* in the context of *subject [has] **just** verbed*, but that's not true. It's just that to the extent Present Perfect *may* be used instead of Simple Past, that stylistic choice is more likely to occur in conjunction with ***just***. But even after ***just***, Simple Past is much more common than Present Perfect.

Comment: what I said about just is true. The British Council says so: https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/b1-b2-grammar/just-yet-still-and-already I've just seen Sai. He's really enjoying his new job. Grammar explanation
We often use just, yet, still and already with the present perfect **because they are related to the present moment**.  This page focuses on the meaning and use of these words when they are used with the present perfect.//I believe that can be called standard grammar.

Comment: @Lambie So the simple past is better in these sentences because it's easier to say? this is just more likely in AE? (and use the PP only if this is important)

Comment: For me, an AmE speaker, I use the PP with just. Many people don't care. It's not about being easier. It's about connection to the present: I've just eaten lunch so I'll wait a while before playing tennis. It's hard for me to imagine "just" being connected to simple past for sentences like that.  But most people do not care. However, I urge you to read the British Council's site.

Comment: @safarie: Don't get *too* committed to this "**just** + Present Perfect" idea. For example, in conversational context, people often say things like ***I just said that!*** and ***I just saw him a few minutes ago.*** But we very rarely use the corresponding Perfect forms ***I have just said that!*** and ***I have just seen him a few minutes ago.***

Answer (score 0):

Both versions are correct.

In the United States, the most common form would be to use the simple past tense. It would be unusual to hear someone use the perfect tense.

> I just clicked on the cross button and nothing happened.

For non-American English, I believe the opposite is true. The perfect tense would be more common than the simple past:

> I've just clicked on the cross button and nothing happened.

You could also use the perfect tense in both parts of the sentence:

> I've just clicked on the cross button and nothing has happened [yet].

Comment: What you say is AmE versus BrE, I say is an educational and situational thing.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. I consider it more cultural. English continues to evolve differently in different locations such as the UK and the US.

Comment: I think it depends on one's education and the actual situation. I don't think this can be broadbrushed into AmE and all other varieties.

Answer (score -1):

The sentence,"I have just clicked on the cross button and nothing happened", is not in past tense.

If we are talking about two actions from past then first one will be in simple past tense and second one will be in past perfect tense. Example  :- We told father that we had broken the window.

If we are talking about two action which will happen in future then first one will be in simple future and second one in future perfect. Example:- we will have gone by the time they will arrive

Action which is happening now will be in present continuous and action which has just completed will be in present perfect.

Comment: We generally do not use *will* for future events in time clauses. It would be much more idiomatic to say *We will have gone by the time they arrive.*